# 'Moving' properties from an object into a new object, based on a 3rd object

Tags: javascript

I have an object which contains multiple properties. For a given list of props in a 3rd object, I want to 'move' the properties from the original object and put them into a new object.

I have a 'longhand' way of doing this at the moment, something like the following. However this creates 2 new objects, rather than just 'moving' some of the keys out:

```
let pets = {
  'cat': {},
  'dog': {},
}

let animals = {
  'cat': 'black',
  'dog': 'white',
  'whale': 'blue',
  'albatross': 'grey',
}

let aPet = {}
let notAPet = {}
for (let [key, val] of Object.entries(animals)) {
  if (key in pets) {
    aPet[key] = val
  } else {
    notAPet[key] = val
  }
}
```

Is there a nicer 'short' way of achieving the above, preferably only creating `aPet` while making `animals` end up equivalent to `notAPet`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [delete operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete):

```js
let pets = {
  'cat': {},
  'dog': {},
}

let animals = {
  'cat': 'black',
  'dog': 'white',
  'whale': 'blue',
  'albatross': 'grey',
}

let aPet = {}
let notAPet = {}
for (let [key, val] of Object.entries(animals)) {
  if (key in pets) {
    aPet[key] = val
    delete animals[key]
  }
}

console.log(aPet, animals)
```